# Adding multiple datatype elements to ArrayList from Scanner

Tags: java, arraylist

Trying to add some student elements (name, age, gpa) into an ArrayList from an input file. I've tried researching materials and think I'm just stuck with a syntax error here, although I'm not sure. I've posted questions on Stack Exchange here that were deemed to generic and was encouraged to add comments and be very specific. What is the proper syntax for adding elements to an ArrayList from an input file? Please let me know if there is anything I can do or add to make my question more clear. Here's what I'm working with:

```
public void readFile() throws IOException
{
    String name;
    int age;
    double gpa; // instance variables

    String line;

    PrintWriter ot = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")); //opens the output file

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Employees.txt"));

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) { 
    //read first line from file 
    name = sc.nextLine();
    students.add(name); // throws error here stating "no suitable method found

    // read next line from file and convert String to int
    line = sc.nextLine();
    age = Integer.parseInt(line);
    students.add(age);

    // read next line from file and convert String to double
    line = sc.nextLine();
    gpa = Double.parseDouble(line);
    students.add(gpa);

    System.out.printf("%s %d %f \n", name, age, gpa);
    ot.printf("%s %d %f \n", name, age, gpa);
   }
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Gives the `NoSuchElementException: No line found` exception, when the input is not in new lines (i.e. all the three attributes of a student). Are you sure all the data starts in new line? (and not per student) For example, "Student1\n12\3.5\nStudent2\16\2.88\n....". However, I suggest to use this format: "Student1 12 3.5\nStudent2 16 2.88...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume 'students' is the ArrayList you are talking about. ArrayLists are type specific, so you won't be able to do this just as you are hoping. However, you should create a 'Student' class that has name, age and gpa as properties, and then you can fill up an ArrayList with Student objects.

After you  have your Student class created, it should be something like this:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) { 
//read first line from file 
name = sc.nextLine();
age = sc.nextLine();
gpa = sc.nextLine();

Student newStudent = new Student(name, age, gpa); //deal with age and gpa parsing inside Student constructor

students.add(newStudent); 

System.out.printf("%s %s %s \n", name, age, gpa);
//should print the same as
System.out.printf("%s %d %f \n", newStudent.name, newStudent.age, newStudent.gpa);

}
```

Comment: Great feedback I appreciate it. In my editor I had to add: Student newStudent = new Student(name, age, gpa); instead of Student newStudent = Student(name, age, gpa); just for anyone else who might come across this.